# Multiple Nivo Sliders - Positioning Unclear

Tags: javascript, positioning, nivo-slider

I am fighting with the positioning of my multiple nivo sliders. I have (in the moment) five sliders which should appear all on the same position, [which can be seen here](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/index_uneplive.php#).

The thing is that the positioning in the code is always the same; but it isn't on the browser's display. When clicking on "Keeping Track" or on "Chemicals & Waste", the slider appears either on the top of the page, or is being only partly displayed.

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px">
    <div id="pagewrap">
        <div class="slidewrap">
            <div id="slider1">
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_fish_stocks.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption2" src="images/geg_fish_stocks_light.png" /></a>
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_protected_areas.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption6" src="images/geg_protected_areas_light.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="slider2" style="margin-top: -350px; visibility: hidden"> <!-- Atmosphere -->
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_temperature.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption4" src="images/geg_temperature_light.png" /></a>
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_indoor_cooking.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption17" src="images/geg_indoor_cooking_light.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="slider3" style="margin-top: -350px; visibility: hidden"> <!-- Biodiversity -->
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_protected_areas.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption6" src="images/geg_protected_areas_light.png" /></a>
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_access_benefit.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption7" src="images/geg_access_benefit_light.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="slider4" style="margin-top: -350px; visibility: hidden"> <!-- Chemicals -->
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_radioactive_waste.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption13" src="images/geg_radioactive_waste_light.png" /></a>
                <a class="lightview" href="images/geg_basel_convention.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption14" src="images/geg_basel_convention_light.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="slider5" style="margin-top: -350px; visibility: hidden"> <!-- Keeping Track -->
                <a class="lightview" href="images/kt_hdi.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption9" src="images/kt_hdi_light.png" /></a>
                <a class="lightview" href="images/kt_food_supply.png"><img alt="Gallery Picture" title="#caption10" src="images/kt_food_supply_light.png" /></a>
            </div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
#slidewrap{
    position:absolute;
    background: #fff;
}    

#slider, #slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5 {
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:915px;
    border:10px solid rgba(89,117,220,0.33);
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #444;
    margin: 0;
}
#slider img, #slider1 img, #slider2 img, #slider3 img, #slider4 img, #slider5 img{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

I am really confused, and have no idea why this would be. Thanks for any hints which could help me solve this riddle.

Plugin activation:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('#slider1').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider2').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider3').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider4').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider5').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider6').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
    $('#slider7').nivoSlider({
        pauseTime: 4000
    });
});
```

Comment: A sample of the JS code applying the plugin to the sliders would be helpful.

Comment: Added the plugin activation. Does this help?

Comment: I think it's, at least partially, a CSS thing. The "style="margin-top: -350px;" for the DIVs seems not to be coherent to me. I guess the $sliderX position should be absolute; I tested it, but nothing changes...

Comment: Nothing? Nobody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution. The problem was in the CSS "height:auto". When I took that away and used 330px instead, it works perfectly well!